# Bootstrap validation with accordation

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I am using bootstrap validtion and accordation with different sections.
Want to keep the panel open where there is a validation error .

Kindly suggest

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It would make sense to add some code to your question so that others can have a look at it.

Comment: show your code and the error message please